# Find the residue of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the residue of $f(z)$

$$f(z) = \frac{z^{(1/4)}}{z+1}$$

So this is a pole of order 1 with a singularity at $z=-1$

$$z^{1/4}\Big|_{-1}\ = (-1)^{1/4}$$

And I'm not sure what to do with that. The book says the answer is $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: Notice that $-1 = e^{πi}$

Comment: So $(-1)^{1/4} = (e^{i\pi})^{1/4} = e^{i\pi/4} = cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$? @kaynex

Comment: @Bellatrix1106 Yes. What are $\cos(\pi/4)$ and $\sin(\pi/4)$?

Comment: Yeah. However, it's also true that $-1 = e^{3πi}$, which gives a different value. Can anyone explain why you wouldn't use this?

Comment: $ = \frac{\sqrt2}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt2}{2} = \frac{\sqrt2 (1+i)}{2} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$ @Mattos Thank you

Comment: The book also states in the answer $|z|>0,\ 0<arg\ z<2\pi$ so I guess it has something to do with the argument? @Kaynex

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the branch cut of the principal logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

The book is not being fair because it didn't give you enough information to solve the problem.  You have a multivalued function.  What is the branch cut?  If the branch cut is the negative real axis, then $\arg{z} \in (-\pi,\pi)$ and you need to know what side of the branch cut you are on.  On the one hand, if you are just above the branch cut, then $-1=e^{+i \pi}$ and the book's answer is correct.  On the other hand, if you are just below the branch cut, the $-1=e^{-i \pi}$  and the answer is instead $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

If the branch cut is taken anywhere else, then $\arg{z}=+\pi$ and the book's answer is correct.